# How to list a two byte value

Tags: python, list, byte, arrays, pyserial

I am using pyserial in Python to communicate serially with a device. I have to read a series of integers from a device. Each element is a 2 byte unsigned short [0 - 65535].
I initialised the port as

```
port = serial.Serial("COM9", 38400, timeout=10.0)
serial.PARITY_NONE
serial.EIGHTBITS
serial.STOPBITS_ONE
data = port.read(50)
```

The data received from the device is

```
 data=b' \xa0G\x0b1\x12\x04\x98\x93A\xcc\xb8\x86\x80V\xf1\xbdp \xc5a\x14\x13\xe8\x8b\x05\xe3P\xc99H\x02\xb8{&\x88\xa6 \x16Q&\xd4\x90j\xea'
```

When the byte is converted to list of bytes, I get

```
data1=list(data)
print(data1)
```

The number of bytes always varies. Giving a sample of output

```
[32, 132, 62, 66, 160, 16, 136, 44, 160, 71, 11, 49, 18, 4, 152, 147, 65, 204, 184, 134, 128, 86, 241, 189, 112, 32, 197, 97, 20, 19, 232, 139, 5, 227, 80, 201, 57, 72, 2, 184, 123, 38, 136, 166, 32, 22, 81, 38, 212, 144, 106, 234, 177, 192, 193, 255, 156, 90, 15, 32, 102, 5, 120, 104, 173, 224, 207, 100, 81, 19, 248, 105, 97, 12, 191, 192, 56, 208, 91, 9, 36, 141, 34, 172, 6, 91, 5, 48, 42, 22, 4, 81, 4, 38, 7, 232, 162, 18, 65, 93, 16, 33, 144, 174, 186, 221, 0, 237, 133, 25, 183, 129, 116, 48, 246, 119, 36, 150, 27, 75, 49, 33, 38, 34, 238, 41, 124, 29, 192, 16, 191, 50, 14, 22, 39, 209, 66, 17, 206, 29, 209, 175, 92, 120, 99, 49]
```

It is not possible to list a two byte value.. The maximum value I can get is 255 using the list method. I am supposed to get values  till 65535.

Using the struct module,

```
from struct import unpack
data1= unpack('H', data)
```

I get the following error

```
struct.error: unpack requires a bytes object of length 15
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here. You want to unpack a 45-byte binary string into 16-bit integers? What are you going to do with the byte that gets left over? The format string `'<10sHHb'` will decode a 10-character string followed by two little-endian unsigned shorts and one signed char. It's no surprise that Python is expecting you to provide 15 bytes of input.

Comment: Is the length of `data` you posted correct? The length needs to be even if you need to read 2-byte integers unsigned integers from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the data posted is not correct, and is just a copy-paste mistake, since you cannot convert a byte array of length `45` to unsigned short array, without losing the last byte.

The format you can use is - `'<' + 'H' * (len(data)//2)` (for litte endian) . This would make the format read in `len(data)//2` amount of unsigned shorts from the `data` byte array. Example (after converting the `data1` array you provided -

```
>>> import struct
>>> s = [32, 132, 62, 66, 160, 16, 136, 44, 160, 71, 11, 49, 18, 4, 152, 147, 65, 204, 184, 134, 128, 86, 241, 189, 112, 32, 197, 97, 20, 19, 232, 139, 5, 227, 80, 201, 57, 72, 2, 184, 123, 38, 136, 166, 32, 22, 81, 38, 212, 144, 106, 234, 177, 192, 193, 255, 156, 90, 15, 32, 102, 5, 120, 104, 173, 224, 207, 100, 81, 19, 248, 105, 97, 12, 191, 192, 56, 208, 91, 9, 36, 141, 34, 172, 6, 91, 5, 48, 4
2, 22, 4, 81, 4, 38, 7, 232, 162, 18, 65, 93, 16, 33, 144, 174, 186, 221, 0, 237, 133, 25, 183, 129, 116, 48, 246, 119, 36, 150, 27, 75, 49, 33, 38, 34, 238, 41, 124, 29, 192, 16, 191, 50, 14, 22, 39, 209, 66, 17, 206, 29, 209, 175, 92, 120, 99, 49]
>>> len(s)
146
>>> data = struct.pack('B' * len(s) , *s)
>>> data
b' \x84>B\xa0\x10\x88,\xa0G\x0b1\x12\x04\x98\x93A\xcc\xb8\x86\x80V\xf1\xbdp \xc5a\x14\x13\xe8\x8b\x05\xe3P\xc99H\x02\xb8{&\x88\xa6 \x16Q&\xd4\x90j\xea\xb1\xc0\xc1\xff\x9cZ\x0ff\x05xh\xad\xe0\xcfdQ\x13\xf8ia\x0c\xbf\xc08\xd0[\t$\x8d"\xac\x06[\x050*\x16\x04Q\x04&\x07\xe8\xa2\x12A]\x10!\x90\xae\xba\xdd\x00\xed\x85\x19\xb7\x81t0\xf6w$\x96\x1bK1!&"\xee)|\x1d\xc0\x10\xbf2\x0e\x16\'\xd1B\x11\xce\x1d\xd1
\xaf\\xc1'
>>> data1 = struct.unpack('<' + 'H' * (len(data)//2) , data)
>>> data1
(33824, 16958, 4256, 11400, 18336, 12555, 1042, 37784, 52289, 34488, 22144, 48625, 8304, 25029, 4884, 35816, 58117, 51536, 18489, 47106, 9851, 42632, 5664, 9809, 37076, 60010, 49329, 65473, 23196, 8207, 1382, 26744, 57517, 25807, 4945, 27128, 3169, 49343, 53304, 2395, 36132, 44066, 23302, 12293, 5674, 20740, 9732, 59399, 4770, 23873, 8464, 44688, 56762, 60672, 6533, 33207, 12404, 30710, 38436, 19227, 8497, 8742, 10734, 7548, 4288, 12991, 5646, 53543, 4418, 7630, 45009, 30812, 12643)
```

Assuming little endian.

Answer (score 0):

Your format to `unpack` is wrong. You're specifying a 10-byte string, followed by two unsigned shorts, then a single signed byte. This adds up to 15 bytes as indicated in the error message. You have a buffer of 45 bytes, so you need to correctly specify exactly what the buffer is supposed to contain.